# Terminology in forcing

Tags: set-theory, terminology, intuition, order-theory, forcing

In the context of [forcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_%28set_theory%29) one reads the relation $p \leq q$ in a poset $P$ as "$p$ extends $q$". A typical example is the poset $P$ of finite partial functions, where one defines $p \leq q$ when $q \subseteq p$. Also, one calls a subset $D \subseteq P$ *dense* if $\forall p \in P \exists d \in D (d \leq p)$.

This contradicts my intuition. Shouldn't $p \leq q$ mean that $q$ is larger than $p$, or that $q$ carries more information than $p$? Why do  texts about forcing turn this around? While reading, I always have to rectify this notation in order to understand the meaning. I also wonder what density has to do with the [usual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order) [notions](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+subcategory) of [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set).

Of course, all this is just a question of terminology, since every poset $(P,\leq)$ has a dual poset $(P,\geq)$ etc.

Comment: I agree with the question about: "What does this have to do with the usual notions of density." An author should never introduce a word like this that is already in common use without either a) showing that it agrees with the common use "with respect to an appropriate topology" or b) explaining that it does not in fact correspond to the usual terminology, so don't go looking for a correspondence. In short: overloading terminology is perfectly acceptable, but at least tell us when you're doing it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two conventions here. Shelah and his collaborators (for example) use the version you indicate as "more natural": That if $p\le q$, then $q$ is a stronger condition, carrying more information.

Many people in the States (myself included) use the other convention. The reason is that, by passing to the Boolean completion of the poset, indeed $p\le q$ corresponds now to $p$ carrying more information. This is explained carefully in a few places. Kunen's **Set theory** book (1st edn.) covers this in Chapter II, section 3, particularly Lemma 3.3.

Some people try to avoid the issue (Foreman does this in some papers), considering only separative posets, and then writing $p\Vdash q$ for "$p$ carries more information than $q$".

Lemma 3.3 in Kunen's book, mentioned above, is also a reference for the natural topology on a poset $\mathbb P$. Here, a basic open set is an $N_p$ where, for $p\in\mathbb P$, we set $N_p=\{q\in\mathbb P\mid q$ is stronger than $p\}$. The term "density", that you ask about, is just topological density with respect to this topology.

Again using this topology, the Boolean completion $\mathcal B$ of $\mathbb P$ is obtained by considering the collection of regular open subsets of $\mathbb P$. Recall that an open set is regular iff it coincides with the interior of its closure. The ordering in $\mathcal B$ is simply containment: $A\le B$ iff $A\subseteq B$. The Boolean algebra operations are then defined as usual in terms of this ordering. This is indeed a complete Boolean algebra. The map $i$ sending $p$ to the interior of the closure of $N_p$ is a function from  $\mathbb P$ into $\mathcal B\setminus\{0\}$ with dense range. If $p$ carries more information than $q$, then $i(p)\le i(q)$, and if $p\perp q$ then $i(p)\cdot i(q)=0$. Forcing with $\mathbb P$ is equivalent to forcing with $\mathcal B$, and some authors prefer to think of forcing in terms of Boolean-valued models, which favors the second convention.

Comment: We [in Jerusalem] call this "Jerusalem convention" and "Universal convention". About half the set theorists in Jerusalem use each convention, both the professors and their students (for obvious reasons).

Comment: I've heard "Western convention" for $p\le q$ meaning $p$ is stronger (is this the "univesal" one?), but I rather avoid that name.

Comment: I have never heard "Western convention" being used, actually. (And yes, that would be the universal one.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, yes. I added a paragraph explaining this.

Comment: Regarding to that last part about Boolean algebras, sometimes it is in fact very convenient to work with Boolean algebras for forcing, even if not working with Boolean-valued models. I did sit through one [notationally] horrible lecture where the lecturer forced in the Jerusalem convention, but worked a lot with Boolean algebras whose order was "downwards". It was quite an uncomfortable experience, I must say.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, many natural forcing iterations are best described in terms of Boolean algebras. I toyed with mentioning this, but figured it may end up being more confusing than illuminating at this point. Funny about your experience, definitely an anecdote to use while exalting the virtues of the universal convention. (I like that name, by the way.)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. But you don't answer my question. Why does Kunen (whose book I currently read) use such a weird definition?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I thought I addressed this, but perhaps being more explicit may help: Boolean algebras carry a natural ordering. Under this ordering, $p\le q$ iff "$p$ carries more information than $q$", not the other way around so, if we want to use Boolean algebras, this is the ordering we want. Any partial order embeds densely in a complete Boolean algebra, so it seems natural to have the order in posets follow this convention as well. Perhaps some intuition is in order: Given a complete Boolean algebra, we may as well take it to be an algebra of sets. (Cont.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg So, if it is an algebra of subsets of $X$, $1=X$, $0=\emptyset$, and $p\le q$ iff $p\subseteq q$. A generic filter is trying to select a "generic" element of $X$. Naturally, smaller sets give us more information about what this generic element is (we have fewer options to choose from). Consider the example of random forcing. The Boolean algebra associated to it is (isomorphic to) the collection of Borel subsets of $[0,1]$ modulo the equivalence relation of having null symmetric difference. (Cont.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Consider Cohen's forcing. This is isomorphic to the poset whose members are intervals of $[0,1]$ with rational endpoints. In both cases, reducing the size of the set gives us more information about what the generic real is. The point is that this is *always* what we are doing, refining our guesses by reducing the size of the pool of candidates. As mentioned in the comments, working with Boolean algebras brings up further advantages (forcing via Boolean valued models, a clean unified description of several forcing iterations), so using its natural ordering seems appropriate.

Comment: "refining our guesses by reducing the size of the pool of candidates." is very instructive. Thank you!

Comment: Andres, no need to quality "generic" with quotation marks. From an algebraic point of view it *is* in fact a generic point. It meets all the dense sets. Surely that would be something @Martin can relate to!